# replace deja puras comas nada mas

Tags: replace

Buenos dias  utilizo replace para cambiar la coma de un numero y poder sumarlos (yas vienen de la base de datos con coma) la suma la realiza bien pero luego necesito poder mostrarlo con coma por lo que despues de obtener el total quiero remplazar el punto por coma y almacenarlo como texto nuevamente y me deja solo comas (,,,,,,)

```
$(".class_superficie").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

        total_superficie += 0;// si no es un numero suma " 0 "

    } else {

        valsup1 = $(this).val()
        
        valsup2 =  valsup1.replace(/,/g, "."); // replace solo funciona sobre texto no sobre numero si es un numero primero a combertir a texto
        //parseFloat($(this).val())
        total_superficie += parseFloat(valsup2); 
      
        //console.log(total_superficie + " total_superficie ++")

    }       

});

        total_superficie = total_superficie.toString()
        total_superficie = total_superficie.replace(/./g, ",")
        console.log(total_superficie)
```

Comment: Pon en las etiquetas el lenguaje que estás utilizando (en lugar de "replace"). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, intenta mostrar un [repro] en la pregunta, agregando un _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`).

Comment: Esto es... javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener el total_superficie formateado lo puedes hacer utilizando `split` y `join` ya que el replace con el `.` no tiene el efecto esperado.

```js
let total_superficie = 0;

const original = '6,52';
const comma_replaced  = original.replace(/,/g,'.');
const comma_replaced_number = Number(comma_replaced);
console.log(typeof comma_replaced_number, comma_replaced_number);

total_superficie += comma_replaced_number;

const formattedFinalTotal = total_superficie.toString().split('.').join(',');
console.log(typeof total_superficie, total_superficie);
console.log(typeof formattedFinalTotal, formattedFinalTotal);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por al pronta respuesta  me funciono tu ayuda, aunque ya lo habia arreglado al remplazar (".", ',')  me gustaria saber por que no funciono en un principio  y lo otro te hago una consulta vos tenes  Number ( ... ) la cual no me reconoce como funcion no se si es por que me falta algo ?

Answer (score 0):

Como ya tienes en formato número, de forma rápida puedes formatearlo a español en el navegador al idioma que quieres. Para más detalles ver [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043659/5675636).

```js
total_superficie = 123.25;
console.log(total_superficie);
console.log(total_superficie.toLocaleString('es-ES'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```